# Ubuntu suddenly stopped booting to GUI and startx stalls

Tags: 12.04, boot, gui

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. A few hours ago, I started up my machine, checked my email, played a couple albums on Spotify and turned it off again. I did not notice anything out of the ordinary and I did not make any configuration changes. Just a few minutes ago, I turned it back on and:

1. The computer posts
2. The boot screen is showed and default boots to my Ubuntu install
3. A screen with the multicolored background and the word "Ubuntu" shows for a split second
4. A command line prompt appears

When I enter the startx command the following is outputted to the screen and then the computer stalls (no gui and no command prompt):

```
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
*checking battery state...
sck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: WARNING: bad format on line 13 of /etc/fstab
/dev/sdb1: clean, 461266/4497408 files, 3928938/17966848 blocks
modem-manager[1043]: <info> ModemManager (version 0.5.2.0) starting...
modem-manager[1043] <info> Loaded plugin X22X
"                                      " LongCheer
"                                      " Option
"                                      " ZTE
"                                      " MotoC
"                                      " Novatel
"                                      " Sierra
"                                      " Linktop
"                                      " Gobi
"                                      " Nokia
"                                      " SimTech
"                                      " Generic
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
*Starting AppArmor profiles
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
*Starting the Winbind daemon windbind
```

I tried commenting out line 13 of fstab, but that didn't make a difference.

I dual boot with a Windows 7 install, but have not booted that for a few days. I have an AMD graphics card that uses the proprietary drivers.

I saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25927/no-gui-boot-startx-error-i-suspect-no-filesystem-corruption) but a comment on the post said the post was dead and if you have similar issues, post a new question.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to comment on your answer, but how did you re-install your Graphics driver. I'm seeing the same thing with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 after setting up the AMD driver. How did you re-install if if you can't boot the machine into Ubuntu?

Comment: @bmcgonag I had to reinstall it from the command line. I followed the instructions on [this](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide) page, under "Installing Catalyst Manually". There is a guide for 13.04 [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide). Make sure to follow the instructions for removing the current driver first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was with my graphics driver. I reinstalled it and everything is working now.